# Verifying resources in a deployment yaml

Tags: kubernetes

In a deployment yaml, how we can verify that the resources we need for the running pods are guaranteed by the k8s?

Is there a way to figure that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your resource [request](https://v1-22.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits) in the deployment YAML. The kube-scheduler will ensure the resources even before scheduling the pods.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: guestbook
      tier: frontend
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-redis
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/gb-frontend:v4
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
```

**How Pods with resource requests are scheduled?** [Ref](https://v1-22.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled)

> When you create a Pod, the Kubernetes scheduler selects a node for the Pod to run on. Each node has a maximum capacity for each of the resource types: the amount of CPU and memory it can provide for Pods. The scheduler ensures that, for each resource type, the sum of the resource requests of the scheduled Containers is less than the capacity of the node. Note that although actual memory or CPU resource usage on nodes is very low, the scheduler still refuses to place a Pod on a node if the capacity check fails. This protects against a resource shortage on a node when resource usage later increases, for example, during a daily peak in request rate.

**N.B.:** However, if you want a container not to use more than its allowed resources, specify the `limit` too.

Comment: @SYN For example, your node has 100Mi available memory, your pod's total request is 80Mi and limit is 200Mi. If the pod is scheduled at your node, it is guaranteed that your pod has at least 80Mi memory allocated for this pod. But how can you guarantee the limit?

Comment: I'm mistaken, requested memory is guaranteed. Whereas the guaranteed QoS class isn't what was asked for. Nevermind

Answer (score 0):

There is QoS (Quality of Service) Classes for running pods in k8s. There is an option that is guaranteing and restricting request and limits. This option is `qosClass: Guaranteed`.

To be able to make your pods' QoS's Guaranteed;

```
Every Container in the Pod must have a memory limit and a memory request.
For every Container in the Pod, the memory limit must equal the memory request.
Every Container in the Pod must have a CPU limit and a CPU request.
For every Container in the Pod, the CPU limit must equal the CPU request.
These restrictions apply to init containers and app containers equally.
```

also check out the reference page for more info :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/

Comment: you can't set a qosClass. the option shows in a pod status, and is granted based on ressources allocation (cpu & memory limits are set, or limits and requests are set and equals)

Comment: This was what I meant actually, I referenced the document. but when I second time reading my reply, yes it was a little bit misexplained, I will edit it quickly. Thanks for the feedback !